# Different types of result for coulmnName = nulll and coumnName IS NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select, postgresql-9.4

I have table Party with columns ***party_Id, party_type***

When I use the below queries, I get two different types of result.

```
SELECT * FROM party WHERE party_type = null
```

Returns nothing

```
SELECT * FROM party WHERE party_type IS NULL
```

Returns all possible rows

**Need a query which should accept both null and values.**

Comment: I don't understand your last question "Need a query which should accept both null and values", can you add some sample data for party_type and the expected outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per SQL standard, comparisons (and boolean operations) use 3-Value logic `(true, false, unknown)`, with unknown being represented by `NULL`. The following expression returns unknown (represented by `NULL`):

```
party_type = null
```

Whereas

```
party_type IS NULL
```

will return a pure boolean `(true, false)`.

You probably want a "NULL-safe comparison predicate":

```
party_type IS NOT DISTINCT FROM null
```

See [Comparison Predicates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE)

Answer (score 4):

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM party WHERE [predicate]
```

return all rows where [predicate] evaluates to TRUE.

The truth table for equals with domain FALSE, TRUE
, NULL

```
=     |    FALSE  |  TRUE  |  NULL
----------------------------------
FALSE |    TRUE   |  FALSE |  NULL
TRUE  |    FALSE  |  TRUE  |  NULL
NULL  |    NULL   |  NULL  |  NULL
```

NULL in this context can be thought of as UNKNOWN, that is if we compare something with UNKNOWN the result is UNKNOWN (including if we compare UNKNOWN with UNKNOWN).

Your first predicate:

```
party_type = null
```

therefore always evaluate to NULL and as a result, no rows are returned from the query.

`IS NULL` is a special predicate that can be used to test if something is null. It evaluates according to:

```
IS NULL FALSE => FALSE
IS NULL TRUE  => FALSE
IS NULL NULL  => TRUE
```

Your second predicate, therefore, evaluates to TRUE when party_type IS NULL and those rows are returned from the query.

Answer (score 1):

NULL means NO VALUE

If you're looking for NULL fields you must use:

```
WHERE SomeField IS NULL
```

In case you need empty (strings) or null fields you should check both conditions:

```
WHERE SomeField = '' OR SomeField IS NULL;
```

Or you can force the result when field is null:

```
WHERE COALESCE(SomeField, '') = ''
```